# Calabash Android Network Stubbing

Tags: android, networking, calabash, stubbing, stubs

I am trying to test an android app using calabash-android, and since network requests usually take time on my internet connection, I want to stub the request in such a way that the data the actual request receives (a JSON string) is available locally in the test suite and an actual network call is never made.

I have already tried using `webmock`'s `stub_request` method and placed it a `webmock.rb` file placed under `features/support` but it still reverts to the actual network request.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Webmock is for ruby projects, you can't stub a java/android HTTP request with it.